# Can I view the status of my servers on my cisco 11503 loadbalancer via a web page?

Tags: cisco

We are changing our load balancer to a cisco 11503, is there a web interface which I can use to see which server's it thinks are currently online?

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly a web interface, but there is software that provides a GUI for the 11503.  It is called CiscoView Device Manager.